# Php Laravel Trying to get property of non object

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in laravel. I got this error in my code.

[image: capture]

---

DataController.php

---

```
// Get Affiliate Data
$data = Commission::where([
  'uploads_id' => $period ,
  'affiliate_code' => $id
])->first();

//Get Last Activity
$lastactivitytxt = null;
$lastactivity = Activity::where('text','LIKE','%Affiliate ['.$data->affiliate_name.']%'); //This is line 168
```

---

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Show more code, where does $data?

Comment: This is probably because `$data` is empty. Check for empty.

Comment: ok, which shows var_dump ($data->affiliate_name); ?

Comment: @rad11 i remove my early comment. the result is still the same, **`Trying to get property of non-object`**

Comment: You are sure your model Commission have column name affiliate_name?

Comment: If you replace first() with count() and do var_dump($data); what u see?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117668/discussion-between-jef-mari-and-rad11).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to get to an object that does not exist in the variable **$data**. Make yourself instead of **first()**, **count()** to check what return you the result. If you get a score> 0, it means that you give not the object, if = 0, it means that nothing was found and trying to get to something that does not exist. You are going to stop in such a way to check if **$data** is not empty string when you use the **first()** or check the **count()** and if it is <= 0 watch out false, and only later try coupled to objects. As you have any additional questions to write greetings!

Answer (score 2):

Use `get()` or `first()` or `lists()` in your query like,

```
$lastactivity = Activity::where('text','LIKE','%Affiliate ['.$data->affiliate_name.']%')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @chanafdo says: $data is empty AKA NULL. You should first check if $data is not NULL.

Also like @vinod-vt mentioned: you forgot to use `get()`, `first()` or `list()` to retrieve your `Activity`s from your database.

Example:

```
// Get Affiliate Data
$data = Commission::where([
  'uploads_id' => $period ,
  'affiliate_code' => $id
])->first();


// Check database resource exists
if (!$data)
{
    // Throw error, 404 or whatever
    return false;
}

//Get Last Activity
$lastactivitytxt = null;
$lastactivity = Activity::where('text','LIKE','%Affiliate ['.$data->affiliate_name.']%')->get(); // You forgot get()
```

Answer (score 0):

just use the ->first() or ->get()

```
$lastactivity = Activity::where('text','LIKE','%Affiliate ['.$data->affiliate_name.']%')->get();
```